# The difference between product scenarios and requirement's Use cases in Software Specifications

Tags: object-oriented, specifications

I am trying to write down a specification for a project ( still a starter ) and I got into the `nuance` between the two sections : `product scenarios` and the following `requirement's Use cases`.

I didn't understand exactly what should the difference between these two sections be. I thought of general Vs specific but that didn't seem right.

Any help and/or resources will be welcomed.

**note :** I am following this template :
https://www.cs.uic.edu/~jbell/CourseNotes/OO_SoftwareEngineering/SE_Project_Report_Template.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Product Scenario is a plain-English (simple language) narrative of a particular scenario for a particular story. It is written in non-technical language.

A Use Case is a UML artifact that is usually modeled in a CASE tool, and represents a *set of scenarios*. The Use Case is something that can be composed into other Use Cases. It is associated with UML artifacts such as Use Case Diagrams, Actor, and other specifically UML terminology. A Use Case Scenario may represent the 'happy path,' exception paths, error paths or other sequences of events that depend on which Actors collaborate when. For example a "Publish Story" Use Case may involve a scenario where the Editor (Actor) is unavailable due to illness and the story is so important that an override authorization is required from a CEO. The Use Case seeks to identify all the ways the system can be touched, through its Scenario set, so that technical requirements can be identified.